# Windows Terminal minimizes instead of hiding when using SW_HIDE

Tags: go, winapi, command-prompt, windows-terminal

I am creating a program in GoLang that has an optional console window. During normal operation, the window will be completely hidden (including the task bar) and I the user will interact with it through the system tray. I want to have an option that shows / hides the console window when the user presses a button in the tray. I've done this before in C# by doing this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

const int SW_HIDE = 0;
const int SW_SHOW = 5;

var handle = GetConsoleWindow();

// Hide
ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);

// Show
ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOW);
```

In order to do this in Go, I used this package: https://github.com/lxn/win. This package is a WinAPI wrapper for Go that will let me use all the same commands. Here is the code I used to do the same thing as the C# code above:

```
win.ShowWindow(win.GetConsoleWindow(), win.SW_SHOW)
```

Now this actually worked perfectly as intended on Windows 10, which does NOT use Windows Terminal by default. I'm running Windows 11 which does use Windows terminal, so I assume that's the reason this is not hiding. Instead, it simply minimizes the window instead of hiding it. Is it possible for me to either force my Go program to NOT use Windows Terminal or preferably get the Windows Terminal to hide like it does with Command Prompt?

Thank you for any help

EDIT: In Windows Terminal, you can go to the settings and set the default terminal application to "Windows Console Host" and that will use command prompt, but this is computer wide. This does fix the problem though. I would like this to just be for my program alone, so the problem still stands, but just making note of it.

Comment: There is no API to force the program to use command prompt.

Comment: This is also a problem with Windows Terminal under C# / .NET ... and the `SetForegroundWindow` / Get trick doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can force your program to use command prompt but i think i might have found a solution.

I also have this problem **but** i'm on python with the same kind of **code / approach** so I would like to appologize in advance if the answer does not fit.

So basically what you will need to do is use `SetForegroundWindow` API to set the handle that you get from `GetConsoleWindow`.

After this you will want to get the handle from the foreground window by using `GetForegroundWindow`.

Now if you hide the window using

```
// Hide
ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);
```

It will properly hide itself from the taskbar.

Example code in python:

```
import ctypes
import win32.lib.win32con as win32con
import win32gui # pip install pywin32
from time import sleep

kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32')
user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32')

a = input('Input value here:')

# get the console window
hWnd = kernel32.GetConsoleWindow()

# set it as foreground
win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hWnd) 

# get the foreground window
hWnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow() 

# hide it 
win32gui.ShowWindow(hWnd, win32con.SW_HIDE)
print("I'm hidden!")

sleep(2)

# show again
win32gui.ShowWindow(hWnd, win32con.SW_SHOW)
print("I'm not hidden anymore!")
```

I hope it helps, and I'm sorry if it doesn't

Comment: That's very interesting and looks promising. If we're both just using the WinAPI, I see no reason why this wouldn't work for me too. I will give this a shot and see what happens. Appreciate it very much!